# 参照されている他のリポジトリもコピーする方法

Tags: git

Git初心者です。Cloneコマンドにてローカルへコピーする際に元のリポジトリから参照されている全てのリポジトリを自動的にコピー(クローン??)することは出来ないのでしょうか？

[追記]
すいません、だいぶ話が飛躍していました。
Git Bashを用いたGitHubからリポジトリのクローン方法についての質問です。
例えば、以下の方のリポジトリをCドライブ下にコピーするとします。
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

$ git clone https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x.git "C:\test"

すると、pluginやwebフォルダが空になっており、コンパイル出来ません。
これを自動で補充してくれるコマンドなどは無いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これでいかがでしょう

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x
```

Comment: すでにチェックアウト済みのところにsubmoduleを追加するには`git submodule update --init --recursive`でいけるはず。試していませんが

Comment: 出来ました！丁寧な回答をありがとうございました。